# How to create a JS Script to show hidden Images in a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I tried to create a Greasemonkey JavaScript script working in the www.instructables.com.
I want from that script to click the "Show All Items" button to load the hidden images.

This is an example page:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Message-in-a-Tin-Can/?ALLSTEPS

This is an example of images I want to show:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fESk.jpg]

Comment: Show the code and specify what is the exact problem. Also use search, there are lots of examples/scripts that click some button.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried a lot of scripts that work well with buttons, but they don't work with the "Show All Items" button.

Comment: That's because that button is added dynamically after the page has been loaded. Look for scripts that use `waitForKeyElements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'show all items' links are the only elements to have class 'photoset-showmore', you can try this

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('photoset-showmore');
    for (key in links) {
        if (typeof links[key]['click'] == 'function')
            links[key].click();
    }
}
```

(you can check it in firefox js console or as greasemonkey script)

Comment: Everything depends on how you use your actual greasemonkey script. If it is loaded BEFORE the content, it is a good idea to use event listener. I've edited the answer, try it again.

Comment: @Alexander Dyachkov It works very well my friend.
Thank you.